# why is my alarm manager getting triggered when i set alarm?

Tags: android

I set a 60 seconds alarm which is supposed to be triggered after 60 seconds, however, whenever i set the time with button click, my onreceive gets triggered and also it gets triggered after 60 seconds as well. how do i fix this?

this is how i am setting my alarm

```
// ENABLE Receiver
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this,
            GhostTimeBombReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Enabled broadcast receiver, Alarm Manager, task will be repeated",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // --//

    // disable any existing alarm
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GhostTimeBombReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // disable any existing alarm

    // ENABLE Alarm Manager
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long recurring = (1 * 1000 * 60); // 60 seconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
            .getTimeInMillis(), recurring, sender);
    // --//
```

and this is my receiver

```
public class GhostTimeBombReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "this toast is called via Receiver",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // ... do what you need to do here...
}
```

}

Comment: Because you're setting the initial alarm time for now. If you don't want that, add 60 seconds to the `Calendar` time somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
        .getTimeInMillis(), recurring, sender);
```

with:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
        .getTimeInMillis()+recurring, recurring, sender);
```